# why is this happening to my jquery ui animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="menu_status_item">
    <span class="menu_status_bar"></span>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#menu_status_item
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;    
}

.menu_status_bar
{
    margin-left: 45px;  
    color: #fff;    
}
```

And this is my jquery

```
var statusMessage = 'Success'
    var colorCode = '';
    var statusText = '';
    if(statusMessage.indexOf("Success") > -1) {
        colorCode = '#33CC33';
        statusText = 'Success';
    }else{
        colorCode = '#CC0000';
        statusText = 'Failure';
    }
    $(".menu_status_bar").css("display", "inline-table");
    $(".menu_status_bar").text(statusText);
    $("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: colorCode}, 4000);
    $("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"});
    $(".menu_status_bar").css("display", "none");
```

Basically i want the text "Success" inside the menu_status_bar to appear, do the animation, and disappear with the display: none.

If i use the display:none at the end, the text won't even show up. If i remove it, the animation works, but the text will remain there... if someone selects it, its horrible because the text will be highlighted.

Does any one know what could this be? or how can i achieve the same result but doing it differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you are not waiting for the animation of `#menu_status_item`to finish before hiding `.menu_status_bar`. Try this: `$("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: colorCode}, 4000, function(){ $(".menu_status_bar").css("display", "none"); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "text doesn't even show up" because the `display: none` is not waiting for the animation to finish. You need to use the animation's callback function to schedule things after the animation finishes.

```
$("#selector").animate({backgroundColor: colorCode}, 4000, function() {
 // callback function
 // only executes after animation is over
});
```

Comment: you are the jedi of jquery, thanks it worked awesomely! :)  did this: $("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: colorCode}, 4000);
 $("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, function(){
  $(".menu_status_bar").css("display", "none")
 } );

Comment: i will mark the answer as correct whenever i can (need to wait 10 minutes)

Comment: FYI, to hide it, you don't need to do `.css({display: none})`. You can just do `$(".menu_status_bar").hide()`.

Comment: I'm surprised this works.  The api (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) suggests that with 3 arguments animate will use the third argument to determine the easing function.  At any rate I'd recommend using .animate( properties, options ) approach because it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @olleicua: It works because the third argument is optional, and is expected to be a string. Since our third argument is a function, jQuery is able to determine that we chose to skip the easing argument.

Comment: I figured as much.  Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @olleicua: The first code example under the section "Basic Usage" shows this.

Comment: Fair enough.  I still prefer the options approach for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, the animate command starts the animation but it doesn't what for it to finish before executing the next line of code.  You want to hide the text after it's done animating.  jQuery provides the 'complete' callback for this:

```
var statusMessage = 'Success'
var colorCode = '';
var statusText = '';
if (statusMessage.indexOf("Success") > -1) {
    colorCode = '#33CC33';
    statusText = 'Success';
} else {
    colorCode = '#CC0000';
    statusText = 'Failure';
}
$(".menu_status_bar").css("display", "inline-table");
$(".menu_status_bar").text(statusText);
$("#menu_status_item").animate({backgroundColor: colorCode}, {
    duration: 4000,
    complete: function() {
        $(".menu_status_bar").hide();
    }
});
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/animate/